# pagination in view page with cakephp2

Tags: cakephp, view, pagination, find

I am developing a simple web-mail client using cakephp2.
For the mailbox list display I am successfully implemented pagination with [Paginator helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html)

Now when I click a particular item in the mailbox list page will show
the message details. In the message display page I also want to show navigation 
e.g **3 of 23 << | >>**

Is it possible to do this with Paginatir helper?

Awaiting your valuable suggestion.
Regards.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Try reading the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html), which handles this topic extensively.

Answer (score 0):

Paginator documentation does not provide information which I have asked for,
But fortunately after a vast reading of Retrieving Your Data section of Model in 
cakephp2.0 documentation I have got my ANSWER.
I have almost done with **find(neighbors)**

[Get Your Neigbor](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-neighbors)

Now I have to set the record number for the current record...then it will be completed.
Thanks for responding..